# Why is only half of my program (3/4 functions) printing in python?

Tags: python

I have a question: I don't understand why my last function isn't going through and printing anything. I tried fixing where I think I might've messed up, but I can't find it. My task is to create function 1 that checks if all the values in a list are unique or not and return true or false, and the second function is the one that generates the random integer list based on user input (function 1 helps with this). After this, I need to find the nth maximum in the list that is requested by the user, which is the part that doesn't seem to be working.

For Example:

```
If the list has the values 1 3 7 2 15 20 5 18 11 and the user wanted the:
```

1st Maximum (n = 1)  -> It would return 20 (the highest number)

2nd Maximum (n = 2) -> It would return 18 (the second highest number)

3rd Maximum (n = 3) -> It would return 15 (the third highest number)

```
#generate list of random numbers
def list_of_nums(start,end,number_of_values):
    nums= []
#how can I let integer also be a negative value with range??
    for i in range(0,number_of_values):
         nums.append(random.randint(start,end))
     return nums


#main function of inputs and calls list
def main():
    number_of_values= int(input("Please enter the number of values you wish to generate:"))
    start= int(input("Please enter the starting # of the values you wish to generate:"))
    end= int(input("Please enter the ending # of the values you wish to generate:"))
    ###
    myList= list_of_nums(start,end, number_of_values)
    allunique(myList)
    print(myList)


#find nth max
def finding_nth_max(nums, nthmax):
    sorted_list= nums.sorted()
    nthmax= int(input("Please enter the nth maximum you would like to find: "))
    print("The nth maximum is", sorted_list[-nthmax])

allunique(myList)
main()
finding_nth_max(myList)
```

Comment: my instructions are: Write a function that accepts a list of integers, and returns True or False depending on if the integers in the list are all unique or not
Write another function that generates a unique list of random integers and returns a list of those values.  Use the previous function to help you with that task.  The function should accept 3 arguments:  The number of values to generate, and the starting and ending values for the random numbers.-

Comment: Write another function that can determine the nth largest number from a unique list of integers. It should accept the list and the value of n as arguments, and return the required maximum.

Comment: You should ask the user to input the following:

Number of Values they wish to generate
The Range of values in the list
The nth maximum value they wish to find
Output:

 Display the unique list and the number the user requested.

Comment: I don't see you calling the function anywhere. You are calling the main function at the very end (with 'main()'), which calls everything in the main function, but your 'find_nth_max' function isn't called there

Comment: ^ neither is `allunique`

Comment: how can I call them?

Comment: like do I write allunique(x) main() and find_nth_max(nums)?? because I tried it on separate lines and it's not working..

Comment: You call them in the place you need that logic to be executed, with the arguments they need. May I suggest redoing a tutorial on functions?

Comment: I think you might be a bit confused about what a function definition does. All you are doing by defining a function is basically telling your PC "hey, see this piece of code? I am giving you this function name to remember and when you see this name somewhere else, I want you to execute this code". Your PC won't do anything with it unless you call the function at some point. So whatever function you want your PC to execute, add it in your main function. allunique(x) will throw an error because your PC doesn't know what x is. Instead you want allunique(myList).

Comment: but when I call that it just says myList is undefined

Comment: are you calling it inside of the definition of main, after myList has been defined?

Comment: i edited my code to show you what im doing.

Answer (score 0):

you must add finding_nth_max(your_list_here) function within your main function, for the output of that function to be printed. This must be added after you have called list_of_nums in your main function

Comment: 1. The function needs an argument. 2. You don't just call it anywhere in the main function, there's a specific place it needs to be called. Please read [answer]

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I've edited my answer, let me know if any other changes.

Answer (score -1):

you need to call method and `nums.sort()` does not return anything, it updates the list automatically

```
def find_nth_max(nums: list):
    nums.sort()
    print(f'provided list: {nums}')
    nthmax= int(input("Please enter the nth maximum you would like to find: "))
    print("The nth maximum is", nums[-nthmax])
find_nth_max([2, 5, 1, 8])
```

Comment: instead of the list at the bottom, how can I replace this with nums?

Comment: @koko can you explain what do you mean by nums?

Comment: nums is the  randomly generated list